# JSONObject Deserialize Directly to Java Object with GSON

Tags: java, gson, json

I'm trying to deserialize my java object `DriverStatus` via GSON. This isn't working, though `gson` `fromJson` takes a `JSONObject` as an argument? What am I missing here? Android Studio wants me to wrap my `JSONObject` with a `stringValueOf`

```
    public DriverStatus deserializeJson(JSONObject jsonObject){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    DriverStatus driverStatus = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, DriverStatus.class);
}
```

Comment: Gson will [reflect into your `DriverStatus` via a passed `com.google.gson.JsonElement`](http://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-com.google.gson.JsonElement-java.lang.Class-), which can be a `com.google.gson.JsonObject`. Check your case (and JsonObject import), as `JSONObject` can likely be from [`org.json.JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) (or other).